# Questions to Ask Existing Vendors of Desktop Applications that we would like to Interface with our Web Application

Tags: asp.net

I am currently involved in a scoping project we are doing with the goal of

Interfacing a Web Application created in a .net framework with SQL Server 2008R2 for the Microsoft platform  and is able to link in with various Patient Management systems (mostly desktop applications) but perhaps with a few web applications.

The idea is that the web application we are creating will be able to pull out selected information (using the Patient ID) from the Patient Management system and is able to pre-populate the Web application with the selected data. The Web application is basically a form with checkboxes, textboxes and lists.

There is a functionality at the end of all that data entry to be able to pull out some reports of interest (I'm not sure at this stage whether this is relevant to this part of the question).

My question is, what sort of questions should I ask the different Patient Management system vendors to enable their system to link in with our Web App?

Many thanks,
Vanessa

Comment: What database are they using, for one...